# error in finalfit::missing_compare: does not find an object

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I am running tests on missing data using the `finalfit` package.

I have a dataset that has 11,046 obs and 27 variables. I have more than one dependent variable because I need later to develop a Confirmatory factor analysis with lavaan. The dataset can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15IhD9tcXZ6Akq5bzN7YBIdUxziqHSkTJ).

```
explanatory_edu <- c("ch_edu", "a4g_4")

dependent <- "br_logical"

sl_cfa %>% 
   missing_compare(dependent, explanatory_edu)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in factor(g, levels = unique(g)) : object 'g' not found
```

What is this `g` object the error is referring to?

This is the output of `ff_glimpse`

```
> sl_cfa %>% 
+   ff_glimpse(dependent, explanatory_edu)
Continuous
# A tibble: 11,046 x 0

Categorical
                label var_type     n missing_n missing_percent levels_n levels levels_count
br_logical br_logical    <lgl>  6398      4648            42.1        2      -            -
ch_edu         ch_edu    <lgl> 11046         0             0.0        2      -            -
a4g_4           a4g_4    <lgl>  8723      2323            21.0        2      -            -
           levels_percent
br_logical              -
ch_edu                  -
a4g_4                   -
```

Not sure it is helpful, but I do not get any error with `missing_pairs`

```
sl_cfa %>% 
  missing_pairs(dependent, explanatory_edu, position = "fill")
```

which gives me this plot

[image]

where we can see that `ch_edu` seems to be MAR and `a4g_4` seems to be MCAR.

PS

Would anyone with the adequate reputation create tags for `finalfit` and `missing_compare` function, please? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.

An underlying function used here is being re-written and the problems caused by tibbles will likely go away.

For now you can:

```
library(finalfit)

explanatory_edu <- c("ch_edu", "a4g_4")
sl_cfa %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  missing_compare(dependent, explanatory_edu)

#> Missing data analysis: br_logical       Not missing     Missing      p
#>                            ch_edu FALSE 4203 (65.7) 1730 (37.2) <0.001
#>                                    TRUE 2195 (34.3) 2918 (62.8)       
#>                             a4g_4 FALSE 2548 (50.5) 1774 (48.2)  0.034
#>                                    TRUE 2496 (49.5) 1905 (51.8)
```

As you mention, missingness in the variable `ch_edu` is strongly associated with `br_logical`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine! One additional question, is there any guideline / rule of thumb on how to interpret the p values (with all the caveat of interpreting p values, of course)? Something like:  > 0.05 is MCAR, between 0 and 0.05 is MAR, below 0 is MNAR? (I am just making up these values to give an idea).

Comment: Thanks. No, the p-value cannot be interpretted in that way I'm afraid.
All you can say is that the data appear NOT to be MCAR, and therefore may be MAR or MNAR.